# php, CodeIgniter- Amazon Product Advertising API, how to get ASIN from a product URL

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, amazon-product-advertising-api

A text box in the page. User will paste a product url from Amazon.com and then click a button beside the text box. Then weight and dimension of the product needs to be received so that these can be utilized later.  pressing the  button  will invoke a jquery ajax call.

From the Amazon Product Advertising write-ups, it seems that  ASIN is necessary first to get any detail from the product. But how can I get the ASIN from the product URL?

A sample product url is: [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B007VBGTX8/ref=s9_ri_gw_g23_i3?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-5&pf_rd_r=0JW9ZMRG6STAF0Y4YV8N&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=358550147&pf_rd_i=468294).

I am using php CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0):

In ruby on rails, I used the following method,so far it works well.

```
def parse_url
    url=self.url.match("/([A-Z0-9]{10})").to_s
    len = url.size
    url=url.slice!(1,len)
end
```

It should be very similar in PHP. Sorry I am not expert with PHP regex syntax.
But good luck! This is base on the ASIN is always 10 char long and start with capital letters, consist with letters and numbers only.